# Why C# get so related with .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net

Maybe there are VB.net and other language that related with .Net framework.

When I install the Visual C++ 2008 ,I have to install the .Net framework 3.5.

However,why people think .Net gets mainly related with C# language?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way of putting this is to compare it to the C languages. The C language is known as the "scripting language of the Von Neuman machine". It is this most expressive of what happens in the underlying machine code.
C# is basically the scripting language of the .Net framework. The .Net framework was designed with C# in mind as its main language, partially because Anders, who designed C# (also Turbo Pascal and Delphi in the past for Borland), was one of the main designers of the .Net framework.
The .Net framework was designed with having high language compatibility in mind, but C# will probably always be the language that is "closest to the metal".

Comment: Thanks.  I just edited and added quotes around it just cause it now sounds even better.

Answer (score 5):

Because people love {curly braces}!

As the [top three most popular programming languages](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) are all curly-braced, it is easy for most programmers to understand and code C# quickly.

C# was also built from the ground up to be .NET language. While VB.NET, in my point of view, is initially created for the existing VB Classic programmers to move to .NET world quickly, and to expand the brand of Visual Basic which people know and love.

Answer (score 3):

It's the most popular language used with .NET.

Answer (score 3):

C# was a cleanly designed object-oriented language that runs with little or no impedance between it and .NET. At least VB was beginning to acquire quite a lot of signs of age, and to be quite frank there were some changes that had to be made to VB when introducing .NET that made a lot of people move on to newer technology.

Answer (score 1):

C# was invented with object oriented programming in mind and .NET Framework relies heavily on OOP concepts. Also, C# was built along side .NET as the language it would primarily support it. .NET has been ported over to C++ and VB as a favor for developers stuck on aged projects.

VB.net is basically an upgraded version of VB that supports OOP but it's not natural because of the structure the original VB has. You'll notice that the syntax in VB will appear confusing or unnatural for complex OOP operations. This is very similar to what happened to C when it became C++.